# how to add an extra character at end of each line in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have the following use case, my file contents look like this

```
a
b
c
```

I want a regular expression to do this

```
a|
b|
c|
```

Can you recommend a regex in vim?

Comment: Lame question. Author hasn't tried to solve the problem himself first sadly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Type the following in VIM

```
:%s/$/|/
```

This means replace the end of line represented by `$` with the string `|`.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for basic scripting purposes

```
 sed 's/$/|/' filename
```

for vim

```
:%s/$/|/g
```

the g is for global, but not needed